# Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked

Tags: android, testing, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

Below is a `repository.`

```
class RepositoryImpl(
        private val service: Service,
        private val dao: Dao,
        private val mainDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Main,
        ): Repository {

        override suspend fun getDataListFromDbAsync(): Flow<List<Item>> = withContext(mainDispatcher) {
                dao.getDataListAsync().asFlow()
        }

/**Some other code*/

 }
```

And the test class is:

```
class RepositoryImplTest {

    private val dao: Dao = mockk(relaxed = true)
    private val service: Service = mockk(relaxed = true)
    private val standardCoroutineDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()
    private val testCoroutineScope = TestScope(standardCoroutineDispatcher)
    private val repository = RepositoryImpl(service, dao, standardCoroutineDispatcher)
    @get:Rule
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(standardCoroutineDispatcher)
    }

    @AfterEach
    fun tearDown() {
        unmockkAll()
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

    @Test
    fun getDataListFromDbAsync() = testCoroutineScope.runTest {
        val dbList = mutableListOf<Item>()
        dbList.add(Item().apply {
            id = 0
            name = "test 0"
            priority = 0
        })
        dbList.add(Item().apply {
            id = 1
            name = "test 1"
            priority = 1
        })
        dbList.add(Item().apply {
            id = 2
            name = "test 2"
            priority = 2
        })

        val mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Item>>(dbList)
        val liveData: LiveData<List<Item>> = mutableLiveData.value?.let { MutableLiveData(it) }!!

        every { dao.getDataListAsync() } returns liveData

        val resultData = repository.getDataListFromDbAsync().toList().first()

        Assertions.assertEquals(dbList.toList()[0], resultData[0])
    }
```

But for the suspend function `repository.getDataListFromDbAsync(),` it gives the below error:

```
Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
    at android.os.Looper.getMainLooper(Looper.java)
    at androidx.arch.core.executor.DefaultTaskExecutor.isMainThread(DefaultTaskExecutor.java:78)
    at androidx.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor.isMainThread(ArchTaskExecutor.java:108)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.assertMainThread(LiveData.java:486)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observeForever(LiveData.java:224)
    at androidx.lifecycle.FlowLiveDataConversions$asFlow$1$1.invokeSuspend(FlowLiveData.kt:97)
    (Coroutine boundary)
    at androidx.lifecycle.FlowLiveDataConversions$asFlow$1.invokeSuspend(FlowLiveData.kt:96)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.AbstractFlow.collect(Flow.kt:230)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__CollectionKt.toCollection(Collection.kt:26)
    at com.package.name.repository.RepositoryImplTest$getDataListFromDbAsync$1.invokeSuspend(RepositoryImplTest.kt:77)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTestCoroutine$2.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:208)
```

Answer (score 4):

Android's `InstantTaskExecutorRule` is for JUnit4, so it seems not applied in JUnit5.
You need to make a custom rule for it.

```kotlin
class InstantTaskExecutorRuleForJUnit5 : AfterEachCallback, BeforeEachCallback {
    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance().setDelegate(object : TaskExecutor() {
            override fun executeOnDiskIO(runnable: Runnable) {
                runnable.run()
            }

            override fun postToMainThread(runnable: Runnable) {
                runnable.run()
            }

            override fun isMainThread(): Boolean {
                return true
            }
        })
    }

    override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance().setDelegate(null)
    }
}
```

then annotate the test class with `@ExtendWith(InstantTaskExecutorRuleForJUnit5::class)`

```kotlin
@ExtendWith(InstantTaskExecutorRuleForJUnit5::class)
class RepositoryImplTest {
    ...
}
```

For the last, there is a mistake in your test case, you need to change `resultData` in the test case to `repository.getDataListFromDbAsync().first()`.

```kotlin
@ExtendWith(InstantTaskExecutorRuleForJUnit5::class)
class RepositoryImplTest {

    private val dao: Dao = mockk(relaxed = true)
    private val service: Service = mockk(relaxed = true)
    private val standardCoroutineDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()
    private val testCoroutineScope = TestScope(standardCoroutineDispatcher)
    private val repository = RepositoryImpl(service, dao, standardCoroutineDispatcher)

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(standardCoroutineDispatcher)
    }

    @AfterEach
    fun tearDown() {
        unmockkAll()
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

    @Test
    fun getDataListFromDbAsync() = testCoroutineScope.runTest {
        val dbList = mutableListOf<Item>()
        dbList.add(Item().apply {
            id = 0
            name = "test 0"
            priority = 0
        })
        dbList.add(Item().apply {
            id = 1
            name = "test 1"
            priority = 1
        })
        dbList.add(Item().apply {
            id = 2
            name = "test 2"
            priority = 2
        })

        val mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Item>>(dbList)
        val liveData: LiveData<List<Item>> = mutableLiveData.value?.let { MutableLiveData(it) }!!

        every { dao.getDataListAsync() } returns liveData

        val resultData = repository.getDataListFromDbAsync().first()

        Assertions.assertEquals(dbList.toList()[0], resultData[0])
    }
}
```